# What is the proof of this binomial coefficient lemma?

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

I have this lemma in my course material, but it came with no proof:

$$ {n\choose k}+{n\choose k-1} = {n+1\choose k}$$

I tried to prove it myself and got quite far I think, but I have no idea how to continue, so I am here asking for help to finish it.

This is how far I got:

$$ \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}+\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}+\frac{n!(n-k)}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}+\frac{n!(n-k)k}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n!+n!(n-k)k}{k!(n-k)!} $$

Comment: You’ve assumed $$(n-k+1)!=\frac{(n-k)!}{n-k}$$ but the right side is $(n-k-1)!.$ The correct value is $$(n-k+1)!=(n-k+1)(n-k)!$$

Comment: Great first question! Welcome to Math SE!

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}+\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}$$
$$=\frac{n!(n-k+1)}{k!(n-k+1)!}+\frac{k\cdot n!}{k!(n-k+1)!}$$
$$=\frac{n!(n-k+1+k)}{k!(n-k+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n-k+1)!}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\binom{n+1}{k}$ is the number of subset of $k$ elements from a set with $n+1$ element. This can be computed as follow : let $X$ a set of $n+1$ element and $x\in X$. There are $\binom{n}{k}$ subset of $k$ element that do not contain $x$ and $\binom{n}{k-1}$ subset that contain $x$. Therefore $$\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the fact that by taking $1$ element out, you can count all $k$ element subsets not containing that element, then add the $k-1$ element subsets to account for the subsets containing that element.

Thus it's rather trivially true, without getting into any algebra.

I believe this is called Pascal's identity.